# syntax error at or near "(" COPY FROM WITH ( FORMAT csv, DELIMITER E'\t', QUOTE '*', HEADER false, ENCODING 'UTF8')

Tags: postgresql

I'm Importing data from a txt file 
This is the table

```
CREATE TABLE test.geonames_load(geonameid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(200),
  asciiname VARCHAR(200),
  alternatenames VARCHAR,
  latitude FLOAT8,
  longitude FLOAT8,
  feature_class char(1),
  feature_code VARCHAR(10),
  country_code VARCHAR(2), 
  cc2 VARCHAR(60),
  admin1 VARCHAR(20),
  admin2 VARCHAR(80),
  admin3 VARCHAR(20),
  admin4 VARCHAR(20),
  population INTEGER,
  elevation INTEGER,
  dem INTEGER,
  timezone VARCHAR(40),
  modification VARCHAR(18)
);
```

After I tried to copy from a txt file

```
COPY test.geonames_load FROM 'C:Program Files/PostgreSQL/8.4/data/US/US.txt' WITH (
  FORMAT csv,
  DELIMITER E'\t',
  QUOTE '*',
  HEADER false,
  ENCODING 'UTF8'
);
```

But it shows me an Error

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: ... FROM 'C:Program Files/PostgreSQL/8.4/data/US/US.txt' WITH (
                                                                      ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
SQL State: 42601
Character: 83
```

Comment: You are missing an `/` on `C:Program Files/P...` it should be `C:/Program Files/P`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of `COPY` has changed quite a bit in version 9.0 compared to 8.4

Assuming you're using version 8.4, based on this `.../PostgreSQL/8.4/...` path,
the syntax that applies is documented here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-copy.html

And it does not allow any parenthesis after the `WITH` keyword that appeared in 9.0, nor the `ENCODING` option that appeared in 9.1

It looks like you need to adapt the statement to your exact version of PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("   Position: 51

For me the reason was due to missing a Column header, eg no middle name header:

**ID, FirstName,  , Surname**

Correcting the CSV file with the header and removing reserved characters from column headers fixed it.